# Change name of file with Grunt

Tags: javascript, file, gruntjs

I need to enter my arbitrary name between the already existing name and file extension, my code:

```
copy: {
  dev: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      src: ['**','.*'],
      cwd: 'copy-test/',
      dest: 'copy-test2/',   
      rename: function(dest, matchedSrcPath) {
                if (matchedSrcPath.substring(0,1)) {
                    return dest  + '_test' + matchedSrcPath ;
                    }
                }
        }]
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`rename`](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) function is the correct feature to utilize for this type of requirement. However, you'll need to  configure your `copy` task with logic defined in the `rename` function as shown below:

---

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt){

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

  grunt.initConfig({
    copy:{
      dev: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'copy-test/',
          src: ['**'],
          dest: 'copy-test2/',
          /*dot: true,*/
          /*extDot: 'last',*/
          rename: function(dest, src) {

            // String to insert into copied filename.
            var str = '_test';

            // Ensure `dest` path has a trailing forward slash.
            dest = /\/$/.test(dest) ? dest : dest + '/';

            // If option `dot: true` is specified any hidden file(s)
            // are copied as is, i.e. the filename is not changed.
            if (this.dot && /^\./.test(src.split('/').pop())) {
              return dest + src;
            }

            // The `extDot` option indicates where the period demarcating
            // the file extension is located. The default value is 'first'.
            // - When its value is 'first' the `str` value is inserted before
            // the FIRST instance of a period.
            // - When its value is 'last' the `str` value is inserted before
            // the LAST instance of a period.
            return this.extDot === 'last'
                ? dest + src.replace(/(\.(?:[^\.]*?)$)/, str + '$1')
                : dest + src.replace(/(\..*?$)/, str + '$1');
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy']);
}
```

---

**Explanation**

The following explains what is happening in the `rename` function, and why it's being carried out:

1. The first part; `var str = '_test';`, is where you should specify the string to insert into the filename(s). Currently the string; `_test`, will be inserted, so you'll need to change this value as necessary.
2. The line which reads;

   ```js
   dest = /\/$/.test(dest) ? dest : dest + '/';
   ```

   ensures the `dest` path always ends with a forward slash (`/`). For instance if the value of the `dest` property is set to `dest: 'copy-test2'`, (note there is no trailing forward slash), then a forward slash (`/`) will be appended. This is necessary to ensure that when the `dest` path and new `src` path are concatenated they form a valid path.

   The code for handling this utilizes the Regular Expression, [`\/$`](https://regex101.com/r/oOtRlD/1) with the [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method, and a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to either; append the trailing forward slash to the `dest` value, or leave the `dest` value as-is if it already ends with a forward slash.
3. The part which reads;

   ```js
   if (this.dot && /^\./.test(src.split('/').pop())) {
     return dest + src;
   }
   ```

   checks if the [`dot`](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files) option is set to `true`. If the `dot` option value is `true`, grunt will also copy hidden files and/or folders as is, i.e. the filename/foldername will not be changed. Any file name and/or folder name which begins with a period (`.`), such as `.gitignore` are recognised as *hidden*.

   *Note: You probably don't want to copy hidden files/folders, however if you do the logic exists for them to be handled correctly when the `dot` option is set to `true`.*
4. The final part which reads:

   ```js
   return this.extDot === 'last'
       ? dest + src.replace(/(\.(?:[^\.]*?)$)/, str + '$1')
       : dest + src.replace(/(\..*?$)/, str + '$1');
   ```

   is where the logic for returning the new destination path occurs. There's quite alot happening here, as described in the following:

   - Firstly, grunt has an [`extDot`](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) option which we utlize to determine where your string (e.g. `'_test'`) should be inserted. The `extDot` option is described in the grunt documentation as:

     > `extDot` Used to indicate where the period indicating the extension is located. Can take either `'first'` (extension begins after the first period in the file name) or `'last'` (extension begins after the last period), and is set by default to `'first'`...

     If you set the `extDot` option to `'last'` then grunt will identify the file extension from a path as shown below:

     ```js
     '/path/to/filename.js'       //-->  '.js'
     '/path/to/filename.min.css'  //-->  '.css'
     ```

     *Note: instead of identifying `.min.css` as the file extension in the second example path - `.css` is identified instead.*

     When the `extDot` option to set to `'last'` the resulant copied filenames will be renamed as `filename_test.js` and `filename.min_test.css`, given the example paths shown above.

     However, if `extDot` is not specified its value defaults to `'first'`, and grunt will identify the file extension from a path as shown below:

     ```js
     '/path/to/filename.js'       //-->  '.js'
     '/path/to/filename.min.css'  //-->  '.min.css'
     ```

     *Note: this time grunt identifies `.min.css` as the file extension in the second example path.*

     When the default `extDot` option (`'first'`) is used the resulant copied filenames will be renamed as `filename_test.js` and `filename_test.min.css`, given the example paths shown above.
   - You'll have noticed that we utilize Regular Expressions in the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to determine where to insert the string (e.g. `'_test'`). Further explanation of each regex can be found at the following links:

     - [`(\.(?:[^\.]*?)$)`](https://regex101.com/r/MzMSCS/3) - for inserting the String before the *LAST* period (`.`).
     - [`(\..*?$)`](https://regex101.com/r/MzMSCS/2) - for inserting the String before the *FIRST* period (`.`).

---

**Note** Files which *do not* have a file extension will not have their name changed.